# Start Visual Studio solution with a project unloaded

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to start Visual Studio with a project unloaded (unavailable at start)?

The reason for this is that, when starting, I often find that Deployment Projects often hangs for about a minute when starting, and they aren't used that often either.

Setting these projects to unavailable and saving the solution doesn't make any change to project file, so if anyone has any suggestions on how to do this (either in Visual Studio proper, or through modifying the XML in the .sln file) I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

> Edit: 2020-09-14: In the interests of keeping this question up to date, I have changed the accepted answer to the [one by Johny Skovdal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822561/31532). The gist of this is that Visual Studio now offers this ability built in ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019#solution-filter-files)) via `.slnf` files.

Comment: Hi, I was able now, on my VS 2010 box to unload a project in the solution, save, close the solution, then I have reopened it and the project was still unloaded/disabled, I can build everything and run the application because that project is not used yet. Is this what you need?

Comment: If you unload a project, exit the solution, and reload it, for me it remains unloaded (just tested VS2010, fairly certain that's true in earlier versions also). However, this setting is stored in each users `.suo` file, which definitely isn't XML, and you can't even mark the file as read-only when it's in the "right" state for you - VS will always overwrite it.

Comment: @DavidePiras: I have tried this, but it doesn't work for me. Also, (assuming this setting is in the solution user file - .suo) it would be nice if VS could let the user choose to save those settings in the .sln file proper.

Comment: Same here. Unloaded both a C++ and a C# project and both were still (unavailable) after reloading.

Comment: ok, hold on a second there is a plugin to do this but don't remember the name now...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It would be nice if this functionality was available in the solution proper, and then it could be dropped into source control...

Comment: @Dan - I can kindof see why this is a per-user setting - if you've got a large solution, and different developers have different "areas of interest" - and I'd far rather they spend time getting rid of all the kludges with .sln and .suo and just gave us real msbuild files :-)

Comment: Here's one: *right click the project* and then *click reload*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2019, this is now [a native feauture called "Solution Filtering"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions), which allows you to have different `.slnf` files you can open instead of your sln file. This keeps the projects you choose unloaded from the get go. This has dramatically increased our solution performance! :)

As for keeping everything unloaded to begin with, there is also a new flag in Visual Studio 2019:

`devenv /donotloadprojects MySln.sln`

From there you can then load the projects you want to include, and then create solution filters, so you can open that the next time around with only those projects preloaded. :)

Comment: Hi! I have changed the accepted answer to yours as it's now 2020 and, whilst I pity the folks still having to use older versions of Visual Studio, I am not, and this is the officially supported method of solution filtering. Thanks.

Comment: @DanAtkinson thanks. :) You might, as we have, run into the issue that changing branches will unload and reload the whole thing. Seems to be a bug inside VS, and can be avoided if you change the branch outside VS (cmd or another gui). Odd, but does the trick. :)

Answer (score 4):

The vsFunnel extension (with VS 2012/2013 support) allows selection of each single project to load, it's also possible to save and re-use the selection at later time:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5396fa4a-d638-471b-ac3d-671ccd2ea369

Comment: Funnel is now broken in vs2017 to date.

Comment: @RJThompson Just a heads up that VS2017 is now working ([release notes](http://vsfunnel.com/releaseNotes.aspx)), although it's arguable that it works as it should.

Answer (score 3):

you can have multiple sln files, one sln file consist deployement projects, other sln file consist projects you need.? just copy your sln file and remove projects you dont need.

Comment: +1 Thank you, but I don't like the separate solutions er... solution. I'd rather have everything in one place, and not have to open another file to do a deployment.

Answer (score 2):

While the Solution Load Manager mentioned in the answer is not updated for VS2012, I found this other [Solution Load Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e96c9847-1ec9-4c0c-8576-bd6575effa07) extension that works.

It is not as complete to where you can choose which projects to load (it load start-up project and its dependencies) but, it is better than loading all projects.

An [interesting MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462384.aspx) explaining project loading.

Answer (score 1):

For a homebrew solution, work needs to be done on the .suo file that is contained in a hidden directory where your solution file lives. For example, if your solution is called .\Business.sln, then the .suo file (for VS2015) is contained at: `.\.vs\Business\.suo`

You can play around with this file by making a backup, loading/unloading some projects, closing the solution, and restoring the backup; this will revert the change you made in the interim. Unfortunately, these backups would almost certainly break as soon as something about the solution changed such as the projects it contains, etc.

As well, this file is not text and I've never sunk the time into investigating if it's possible to migrate it to text and back.

This answer isn't a answer in the sense that it answers the question, but it's a lead in case anyone else reads and has an idea. I've wanted to source control a sort of blank-slate .suo file for years, along with a TFS source control hint to ignore such a file for source control binding. The intended result was that when users get a branch for the first time, their solutions default to loading no projects, allowing them to selectively load only what they want; however, with the source control hint no such changes would ever be picked up by TFS nor checked in, such that this setup imposed no administrative headache.

Dreams!